# Latest Magento 1.9.3.6 and Magento Security Scan Tool , not patched?

Tags: patches, magento-1.9.3.6

I have the latest vetsion of Magento x1 version, which is 1.9.3.6. 
It says it

- Includes patches: SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285, SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7616, SUPEE-7405, SUPEE-7405 v1.1, SUPEE-8788, SUPEE-9652, SUPEE-8167, SUPEE-9767v2, SUPEE-10266

However, when I run Magento Security Scan Tool, it says

> SUPEE-9767 - Failed. Outdated JQuery library found (APPSEC-1622), got
>   '302'.

Should I do something?

Comment: Have you checked your website in https://www.magereport.com?

Comment: It says 9767 is installed.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue on EE.

The 9767 patch replaced `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` with `jquery-1.12.0.min.js` in the frontend layout XML files.

Search your codebase for **"1.10.2.min.js"** and see what you find - I suspect you have a custom layout XML in one of your themes that is still referencing jquery-1.10.2.min.js, causing the security scanner to assume that 9767 hasn't been applied. If so, replace it with `lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js` (or wherever it might be located in your project).